# Can AJAX calling a external webservices functions

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, web-services

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="WebService.asmx" />
            </Services>
   </asp:ScriptManager> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
            WebService.GetUpdate("hhh",OnComplete, OnTimeout, OnError);
    </script>
```

this code is working fine, but when I change the Path to an external webservices, it give me an error, the class name is not defined. can someone help me out, thanks
the changed one is

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://mysite/WebService.asmx" />
            </Services>
   </asp:ScriptManager> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
            WebService.GetUpdate("hhh",OnComplete, OnTimeout, OnError);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a call to the local server, and have the server make the call to the external web service.  This is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using Javascript to make cross-domain calls, if you can change the web service implementation, your can make the cross-domain calls in web service, then retrieve the result from your client.

With Javascript, as far as I know, some Javascript libraries (like dojo) have support for this. Below is a sample code snippet.

```
var callee = dojox.io.windowName.send("GET", {url:"http://xyz.com/data"});
callee.addCallback(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Jay has the right idea, just don't send a full url as that opens you up to attacks.  Just send an enumerated value (1 for xyz url, 2 for abc url, etc)

Comment: @allen - um... huh? do you have a majic dns server that will translate '1' to 'xyz.com'? ;-)

Comment: the enumeration would be stored on the server and the server would know to translate 1 to 'xyz.com', and so on. It would then make the call, on the server side, and return the data back. It'd basically be a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a cross-domain call: you can’t make XMLHttpRequest calls from one domain to another.

Comment: To Scobal, do u know how to make the cross-domain calls using javascript, thanks

Comment: As Brian said above you need a proxy on the same domain. Check out this article: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

using the local webservice to call the external webservices and then use javascript to call the local function, then the problem solved

Answer (score -1):

You can only reference a web service in the same domain using the ServiceReference

Comment: @zincorp,
do u know how to make the calls in a different domain